# Impulse, gaussian and salt and pepper noise with OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I'm studying Image Processing on the famous [Gonzales "Digital Image Processing"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013168728X) and talking about image restoration a lot of examples are done with computer-generated noise (gaussian, salt and pepper, etc). In MATLAB there are some built-in functions to do it. What about OpenCV?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As far as I know there are no convenient built in functions like in Matlab. But with only a few lines of code you can create those images yourself.

For example additive gaussian noise:

```
Mat gaussian_noise = img.clone();
randn(gaussian_noise,128,30);
```

Salt and pepper noise:

```
Mat saltpepper_noise = Mat::zeros(img.rows, img.cols,CV_8U);
randu(saltpepper_noise,0,255);

Mat black = saltpepper_noise < 30;
Mat white = saltpepper_noise > 225;

Mat saltpepper_img = img.clone();
saltpepper_img.setTo(255,white);
saltpepper_img.setTo(0,black);
```

Answer (score 22):

There is function [`random_noise()`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.util.html#random-noise) from the scikit-image package. It has several builtin noise patterns, such as `gaussian`, `s&p` (for salt and pepper noise), `possion` and `speckle`.

Below I show an example of how to use this method

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from skimage.util import random_noise

im = Image.open("test.jpg")
# convert PIL Image to ndarray
im_arr = np.asarray(im)

# random_noise() method will convert image in [0, 255] to [0, 1.0],
# inherently it use np.random.normal() to create normal distribution
# and adds the generated noised back to image
noise_img = random_noise(im_arr, mode='gaussian', var=0.05**2)
noise_img = (255*noise_img).astype(np.uint8)

img = Image.fromarray(noise_img)
img.show()
```

[image]

There is also a package called [imgaug](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug) which are dedicated to augment images in various ways. It provides gaussian, poissan and salt&pepper noise augmenter. Here is how you can use it to add noise to image:

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from imgaug import augmenters as iaa


def main():
    im = Image.open("bg_img.jpg")
    im_arr = np.asarray(im)

    # gaussian noise
    # aug = iaa.AdditiveGaussianNoise(loc=0, scale=0.1*255)

    # poisson noise
    # aug = iaa.AdditivePoissonNoise(lam=10.0, per_channel=True)

    # salt and pepper noise
    aug = iaa.SaltAndPepper(p=0.05)

    im_arr = aug.augment_image(im_arr)

    im = Image.fromarray(im_arr).convert('RGB')
    im.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thx for sharing imgaug.

Answer (score 13):

> Simple Function to add Gaussian, Salt-pepper speckle and poisson noise to an image

```
Parameters
----------
image : ndarray
    Input image data. Will be converted to float.
mode : str
    One of the following strings, selecting the type of noise to add:

    'gauss'     Gaussian-distributed additive noise.
    'poisson'   Poisson-distributed noise generated from the data.
    's&p'       Replaces random pixels with 0 or 1.
    'speckle'   Multiplicative noise using out = image + n*image,where
                n,is uniform noise with specified mean & variance.

import numpy as np
import os
import cv2

def noisy(noise_typ,image):

if noise_typ == "gauss":
        row,col,ch= image.shape
        mean = 0
        #var = 0.1
       #sigma = var**0.5
        gauss = np.random.normal(mean,1,(row,col,ch))
        gauss = gauss.reshape(row,col,ch)
        noisy = image + gauss
        return noisy
    elif noise_typ == "s&p":
        row,col,ch = image.shape
        s_vs_p = 0.5
        amount = 0.004
        out = image
        # Salt mode
        num_salt = np.ceil(amount * image.size * s_vs_p)
        coords = [np.random.randint(0, i - 1, int(num_salt))
                  for i in image.shape]
        out[coords] = 1

        # Pepper mode
        num_pepper = np.ceil(amount* image.size * (1. - s_vs_p))
        coords = [np.random.randint(0, i - 1, int(num_pepper))
                  for i in image.shape]
        out[coords] = 0
        return out
    elif noise_typ == "poisson":
        vals = len(np.unique(image))
        vals = 2 ** np.ceil(np.log2(vals))
        noisy = np.random.poisson(image * vals) / float(vals)
        return noisy
    elif noise_typ =="speckle":
        row,col,ch = image.shape
        gauss = np.random.randn(row,col,ch)
        gauss = gauss.reshape(row,col,ch)        
        noisy = image + image * gauss
        return noisy
```

Comment: When I use the gaussian type my image becomes all white. I'm doing something like that: image = cv2.imread(fn) noise_gauss = noisy("gauss", image) cv2.imshow("gauss", noise_gauss). It seems the generated noise is not of the same type and the addition causes some weird transformation

Comment: @Lxu can you show what this transformation looks like?

Comment: @Lxu I believe this is because the numpy array type turned to `float64`. Just write `noise_gauss = noise_gauss.astype('uint8')` before you pass it to the `cv2.imshow`

Comment: @Lux Make sure you scaled the image pixel values to 0 to 1 by divide the image by 255

Answer (score 8):

"Salt & Pepper" noise can be added in a quite simple fashion using NumPy matrix operations.

```py
def add_salt_and_pepper(gb, prob):
    '''Adds "Salt & Pepper" noise to an image.
    gb: should be one-channel image with pixels in [0, 1] range
    prob: probability (threshold) that controls level of noise'''
    
    rnd = np.random.rand(gb.shape[0], gb.shape[1])
    noisy = gb.copy()
    noisy[rnd < prob] = 0
    noisy[rnd > 1 - prob] = 1
    return noisy
```

Answer (score 8):

```py
# Adding noise to the image    

import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

img = cv2.imread('./fruit.png',0)
im = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8) # do not use original image it overwrites the image
mean = 0
sigma = 10
cv2.randn(im,mean,sigma) # create the random distribution
Fruit_Noise = cv2.add(img, im) # add the noise to the original image
plt.imshow(Fruit_Noise, cmap='gray')
```

The values of mean and sigma can be altered to bring about a specific change in noise like gaussian or pepper-salt noise etc.
You can use either randn or randu according to the need. Have a look at the documentation: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cv2.randu

Comment: Your code really does the job, but only in one channel. You need mean/sigma to be a tuple of values like: sigma = (10, 10, 10)

Answer (score 3):

I made some change of @Shubham Pachori 's code. When reading a image into numpy arrary, the default dtype is uint8, which can cause wrapping when adding noise onto the image.

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

"""
image: read through PIL.Image.open('path')
sigma: variance of gaussian noise
factor: the bigger this value is, the more noisy is the poisson_noised image

##IMPORTANT: when reading a image into numpy arrary, the default dtype is uint8,
which can cause wrapping when adding noise onto the image. 
E.g,  example = np.array([128,240,255], dtype='uint8')
     example + 50 = np.array([178,44,49], dtype='uint8')
Transfer np.array to dtype='int16' can solve this problem.
"""


def gaussian_noise(image, sigma):
    img = np.array(image)
    noise = np.random.randn(img.shape[0], img.shape[1], img.shape[2])
    img = img.astype('int16')
    img_noise = img + noise * sigma
    img_noise = np.clip(img_noise, 0, 255)
    img_noise = img_noise.astype('uint8')
    return Image.fromarray(img_noise)


def poisson_noise(image, factor):
    factor = 1 / factor
    img = np.array(image)
    img = img.astype('int16')
    img_noise = np.random.poisson(img * factor) / float(factor)
    np.clip(img_noise, 0, 255, img_noise)
    img_noise = img_noise.astype('uint8')
    return Image.fromarray(img_noise)
```

Answer (score 2):

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.random_noise

```py
skimage.util.random_noise(image, mode='gaussian', seed=None, clip=True, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Actually it is bad style to have most of the question in an URL (that might vanish), so please do not repeat that for the answer! Try to write the essential solution in the input box, and use code formatting to, well, format code.

Answer (score -1):

```py
#Adding noise
[m,n]=img.shape
saltpepper_noise=zeros((m, n));
saltpepper_noise=rand(m,n); #creates a uniform random variable from 0 to 1 
for i in range(0,m):
    for j in range(0,n):
        if saltpepper_noise[i,j]<=0.5:
            saltpepper_noise[i,j]=0
        else:
            saltpepper_noise[i,j]=255
```

Answer (score -1):

although there is no built-in functions like in matlab
`imnoise(image,noiseType,NoiseLevel)` but we can easily add required amount random
valued impulse noise or salt and pepper into an image manually.

1. to add random valued impulse noise.

   ```py
   import random as r
   def addRvinGray(image,n): # add random valued impulse noise in grayscale 
       '''parameters: 
            image: type=numpy array. input image in which you want add noise.
            n:  noise level (in percentage)'''
       k=0                  # counter variable 
       ih=image.shape[0]    
       iw=image.shape[1]
       noisypixels=(ih*iw*n)/100      # here we calculate the number of pixels to be altered.

       for i in range(ih*iw):
           if k<noisypixels:
                   image[r.randrange(0,ih)][r.randrange(0,iw)]=r.randrange(0,256) #access random pixel in the image gives random intensity (0-255)              
               k+=1
           else:
               break
       return image
   ```
2. to add salt and pepper noise

   ```py
   def addSaltGray(image,n): #add salt-&-pepper noise in grayscale image

       k=0
       salt=True
       ih=image.shape[0]
       iw=image.shape[1]
       noisypixels=(ih*iw*n)/100

       for i in range(ih*iw):
            if k<noisypixels:  #keep track of noise level
                if salt==True:
                        image[r.randrange(0,ih)][r.randrange(0,iw)]=255
                        salt=False
                else:
                        image[r.randrange(0,ih)][r.randrange(0,iw)]=0
                        salt=True
                k+=1
            else:
                break
       return image
   ```

Note: for color images: first split image in to three or four channels depending on the input image using opencv function:

```py
(B, G, R) = cv2.split(image)
(B, G, R, A) = cv2.split(image)
```

after spliting perform the same operations on all channels.
at the end merge all the channels:

```py
merged = cv2.merge([B, G, R])
return merged
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
def add_salt_noise(src, ratio: float = 0.05, noise: list = [0, 0, 0]):
    dst = src.copy()
    import random
    shuffle_dict = {}
    i = 0
    while i < (int(dst.shape[0]*dst.shape[1] * ratio)):
        x, y = random.randint(0, dst.shape[0] - 1), random.randint(0, dst.shape[1] - 1)
        if (x, y) in shuffle_dict:
            continue
        else:
            dst[x, y] = noise
            shuffle_dict[(x, y)] = 0
            i += 1
    return dst
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).