# How to add noise (Gaussian/salt and pepper etc) to image in Python with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am wondering if there exists some functions in Python with OpenCV or any other python image processing library that adds Gaussian or salt and pepper noise to an image? For example, in MATLAB there exists straight-forward functions that do the same job.

Or, how to add noise to an image using Python with OpenCV?

Comment: Have you tried searching? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435632/impulse-gaussian-and-salt-and-pepper-noise-with-opencv for example

Comment: @Cyber Yes I know about them, but they are for MATLAB. They are MATLAB functions for adding noise in the image. But, my question is doing the same while using python and opencv.

Comment: @Sanchit, the answer for question mentioned by Cyber is not Matlab but OpenCV

Comment: @MichaelBurdinov: Sorry I mistakenly looked into another page (they are using MATLAB functions). Yes, I think this concept can be used (for Gaussian noise). I give a try to it.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

> The Function adds gaussian , salt-pepper , poisson and speckle noise in an image

```
Parameters
----------
image : ndarray
    Input image data. Will be converted to float.
mode : str
    One of the following strings, selecting the type of noise to add:

    'gauss'     Gaussian-distributed additive noise.
    'poisson'   Poisson-distributed noise generated from the data.
    's&p'       Replaces random pixels with 0 or 1.
    'speckle'   Multiplicative noise using out = image + n*image,where
                n is uniform noise with specified mean & variance.


import numpy as np
import os
import cv2
def noisy(noise_typ,image):
   if noise_typ == "gauss":
      row,col,ch= image.shape
      mean = 0
      var = 0.1
      sigma = var**0.5
      gauss = np.random.normal(mean,sigma,(row,col,ch))
      gauss = gauss.reshape(row,col,ch)
      noisy = image + gauss
      return noisy
   elif noise_typ == "s&p":
      row,col,ch = image.shape
      s_vs_p = 0.5
      amount = 0.004
      out = np.copy(image)
      # Salt mode
      num_salt = np.ceil(amount * image.size * s_vs_p)
      coords = [np.random.randint(0, i - 1, int(num_salt))
              for i in image.shape]
      out[coords] = 1

      # Pepper mode
      num_pepper = np.ceil(amount* image.size * (1. - s_vs_p))
      coords = [np.random.randint(0, i - 1, int(num_pepper))
              for i in image.shape]
      out[coords] = 0
      return out
  elif noise_typ == "poisson":
      vals = len(np.unique(image))
      vals = 2 ** np.ceil(np.log2(vals))
      noisy = np.random.poisson(image * vals) / float(vals)
      return noisy
  elif noise_typ =="speckle":
      row,col,ch = image.shape
      gauss = np.random.randn(row,col,ch)
      gauss = gauss.reshape(row,col,ch)        
      noisy = image + image * gauss
      return noisy
```

Comment: ouput image `noise_img = sp_noise(image,0.05)
cv2.imwrite('sp_noise.jpg', noise_img)` size 0

Comment: this 'salt and pepper' method adds to each color channel individually. some examples I have seen show black and white speckles even for a color image.... which is correct or realistic?

Comment: what is the meaning of s_vs_p and amount?

Comment: for color images it probably makes sense to do it in HSV space and then convert to RGV

Comment: I guess u should change 1 as salt to 255 if it's RGB

Comment: @Shubham Pachori In the Poisson case: it's as if you want to induce more noise for brighter pixels.  Can you explain your motivation?

Comment: Bugs in gauss and s&p cases... my answer below

Comment: The s&p answer gives `FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use arr[tuple(seq)] instead of arr[seq]. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, arr[np.array(seq)], which will result either in an error or a different result.` in newer versions of Numpy

Comment: One additional thing, the speckle noise you're introducing has variance 1. This is because randn() gives randomly sampled floats from a normal gaussian distribution. To control the speckle noise variance you would use `noisy = image + image * gauss * variance`

Comment: I just realized, that np.random.randint already has an exclusive upper bound and the -1 in np.random.randint(0, i - 1) is wrong. For color images it prevents blue to be noisy in the s&p case.

Answer (score 26):

I don't know is there any method in Python API.But you can use this simple code to add Salt-and-Pepper noise to an image.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import cv2

def sp_noise(image,prob):
    '''
    Add salt and pepper noise to image
    prob: Probability of the noise
    '''
    output = np.zeros(image.shape,np.uint8)
    thres = 1 - prob 
    for i in range(image.shape[0]):
        for j in range(image.shape[1]):
            rdn = random.random()
            if rdn < prob:
                output[i][j] = 0
            elif rdn > thres:
                output[i][j] = 255
            else:
                output[i][j] = image[i][j]
    return output

image = cv2.imread('image.jpg',0) # Only for grayscale image
noise_img = sp_noise(image,0.05)
cv2.imwrite('sp_noise.jpg', noise_img)
```

Comment: Good one. That is working well

Comment: Simple and to the point.  Thanks.  I would recommend doing this with vectorized operations for efficiency since you're using NumPy arrays.

Comment: I implemented a vectorized version based on this answer here: https://gist.github.com/lucaswiman/1e877a164a69f78694f845eab45c381a

It is indeed much faster.

Comment: Why you took rdn>thres to add salt noise?

Comment: any reason this would change color of the image?

Answer (score 12):

just look at [cv2.randu()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cv2.randu)  or cv.randn(),  it's all pretty similar to matlab already, i guess.

let's play a bit ;) :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

>>> im = np.empty((5,5), np.uint8) # needs preallocated input image
>>> im
array([[248, 168,  58,   2,   1],  # uninitialized memory counts as random, too ?  fun ;) 
       [  0, 100,   2,   0, 101],
       [  0,   0, 106,   2,   0],
       [131,   2,   0,  90,   3],
       [  0, 100,   1,   0,  83]], dtype=uint8)
>>> im = np.zeros((5,5), np.uint8) # seriously now.
>>> im
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
>>> cv2.randn(im,(0),(99))         # normal
array([[  0,  76,   0, 129,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, 188,  27],
       [  0, 152,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0, 134,  79,   0],
       [  0, 181,  36, 128,   0]], dtype=uint8)
>>> cv2.randu(im,(0),(99))         # uniform
array([[19, 53,  2, 86, 82],
       [86, 73, 40, 64, 78],
       [34, 20, 62, 80,  7],
       [24, 92, 37, 60, 72],
       [40, 12, 27, 33, 18]], dtype=uint8)
```

to apply it to an existing image, just generate noise in the desired range, and add it:

```
img = ...
noise = ...

image = img + noise
```

Comment: Executing this `cv2.randn(im,(0),(99))` won't return array as shown in the answer. It returns NoneType . Please print `im` array to check the random values. [randn](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#randn)

Comment: Maybe you could change dtype=np.int8 as compared to uint8. That way, the noise can also be negative and the overall brightness stays roughly the same. With this solution it is only getting brighter.

Comment: I'd suggest `cv2.add(img, noise)` because `img+noise` would give undesirable results . This is because opencv hanldles `250+10` as `255` while numpy would handle it as `(250+10)%255 = 5`