# How can I plot random pixels in real time in Python?

Tags: python, plot, real-time-data

I'm almost a beginner in Python even though I did Computer Sciences.

I'd like to do several projects with real-time Python plotting.

My start is to display an image with random pixels constantly changing. 
I tried Python interactive mode, and loops, but I can't figure it out.

Here is the code to show random pixels :

```
import matplotlib
from numpy import random

Z = random.random((50,50))   # Test data
imshow(Z, cmap=get_cmap("Spectral"), interpolation='nearest')
fig.show()
```

What would be an easy way to replace all pixels with new random ones each frame ? (Like a TV noise)
Thanks for help !

Comment: does this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27342545/5612363?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a plot between making changes you can use plt.pause(time_in_s):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from numpy import random

for i in range(20):
    Z = random.random((50,50))   # Test data
    plt.imshow(Z, cm.get_cmap("Spectral"), interpolation='nearest')
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(0.01)
```

For more complex animations, see https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#module-matplotlib.animation 
or
https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/

Comment: It doesn't work for me, It's updating only if I close the plot window :O

Comment: are you using an IDE? I'm working with spyder and it works without issues. Maybe try to change the time in `plt.pause(0.01)` to some higher values, e.g. 1