# Problem with adding Noise to a grayscale image with Python

Tags: python, image, gaussian, grayscale, whitenoise

I tried to add a gaussian noise to a grayscale image with something like:

```
noise = np.random.normal(0, sigma, img.shape(img))
img = img + noise
```

The problem is that i got a noisy image when i save it with io.imsave() but not with same one that i used in Matlab, there is some differance in contrast i think because of this statement :Lossy conversion from float64 to uint8. Range [-1713.9923310279846, 1488.4250569343567]. Convert image to uint8 prior to saving to suppress this warning.

So even when i tried to convert it to uint8 i get as a result, an image with white points or event a dark image with some white points. Any idea to solve this lossy conversion that didn't let me get the right noisy image as i want.

Comment: `img.shape(img)` does this even work? It should give an exception as `img.shape` is a `Tuple`

Comment: Also, what is `sigma`? I would have followed something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30609854/712452

Comment: No, it's np.shape(img). It was a mistake when i wrote this topic.

Comment: sigma, is a value for intensity of the noise.
More like standard deviation var