# How to add Noise to Color Image - Opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, noise

I'm trying to to add noise to an Image & then Denoise it to test my DeNoising algorithm! So for benchmark i'm referring this [Online Test samples](http://demo.ipol.im/demo/125/). I'm trying to replicate the Noise model.

With reference to this threads [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435632/impulse-gaussian-and-salt-and-pepper-noise-with-opencv) , [2](http://answers.opencv.org/question/36309/opencv-gaussian-noise/)  I'm adding noise to image like this!

```
Mat mSource_Bgr;
mSource_Bgr= imread(FileName_S,1);

double m_NoiseStdDev=10;

Mat mNoise_Bgr = mSource_Bgr.clone();
Mat mGaussian_noise = Mat(mSource_Bgr.size(),CV_8UC3);

randn(mGaussian_noise,0,m_NoiseStdDev);
mNoise_Bgr += mGaussian_noise;

normalize(mNoise_Bgr,mNoise_Bgr,0, 255, CV_MINMAX, CV_8UC3);

imshow("Output Window",mNoise_Bgr);
//imshow("Gaussian Noise",mGaussian_noise);
```

My Input Image
[image]

Output Image with Noise
[image]

**Problem:**

**Adding Noise** to the image **alters overall brightness of the Image** which in turn alters my final results PSNR!

I want to get the results as much as closer [to this one](http://demo.ipol.im/demo/g_tv_denoising/input_select?alley.x=85&alley.y=34)!
[image]

What i have tried so far!

I have tried to add the noise only in the color channel.

1. Convert the Input image into YUV Color space
2. Add the Noise only in the UV Color Channels & Keep the Y channel unaltered.

   Results are very bad & the overall color of the image is getting altered! Will add the code if needed!

So any advice regarding this is much appreciated! May be give me some formulas for adding Noise to the image!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your noise matrix can't get negative values as it have unsigned char element type. Try operate with real valued matrices, it should help.

Comment: Normal distributed zero centered noise range will be both sides positive and negative. CV_8UC3 will trim negative part, so mean value will be greater than zero, this will shift average brightness of image.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you @Andrey Smorodov For your insights! 
I got it working! Here is my updated code for adding Noise in a Color Image. Hope this will be useful for someone!

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

inline BYTE Clamp(int n)
{
    n = n>255 ? 255 : n;
    return n<0 ? 0 : n;
}

bool AddGaussianNoise(const Mat mSrc, Mat &mDst,double Mean=0.0, double StdDev=10.0)
{
    if(mSrc.empty())
    {
        cout<<"[Error]! Input Image Empty!";
        return 0;
    }

    Mat mGaussian_noise = Mat(mSrc.size(),CV_16SC3);
    randn(mGaussian_noise,Scalar::all(Mean),Scalar::all(StdDev));

    for (int Rows = 0; Rows < mSrc.rows; Rows++)
    {
        for (int Cols = 0; Cols < mSrc.cols; Cols++)
        {
            Vec3b Source_Pixel= mSrc.at<Vec3b>(Rows,Cols);
            Vec3b &Des_Pixel= mDst.at<Vec3b>(Rows,Cols);
            Vec3s Noise_Pixel= mGaussian_noise.at<Vec3s>(Rows,Cols);

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                int Dest_Pixel= Source_Pixel.val[i] + Noise_Pixel.val[i];
                Des_Pixel.val[i]= Clamp(Dest_Pixel);
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool AddGaussianNoise_Opencv(const Mat mSrc, Mat &mDst,double Mean=0.0, double StdDev=10.0)
{
    if(mSrc.empty())
    {
        cout<<"[Error]! Input Image Empty!";
        return 0;
    }
    Mat mSrc_16SC;
    Mat mGaussian_noise = Mat(mSrc.size(),CV_16SC3);
    randn(mGaussian_noise,Scalar::all(Mean), Scalar::all(StdDev));

    mSrc.convertTo(mSrc_16SC,CV_16SC3);
    addWeighted(mSrc_16SC, 1.0, mGaussian_noise, 1.0, 0.0, mSrc_16SC);
    mSrc_16SC.convertTo(mDst,mSrc.type());

    return true;
}


int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    Mat mSource= imread("input.png",1); 
    imshow("Source Image",mSource);

    Mat mColorNoise(mSource.size(),mSource.type());

    AddGaussianNoise(mSource,mColorNoise,0,10.0);

    imshow("Source + Color Noise",mColorNoise); 


    AddGaussianNoise_Opencv(mSource,mColorNoise,0,10.0);//I recommend to use this way!

    imshow("Source + Color Noise OpenCV",mColorNoise);  

    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly two methods to add say awgn noise (mean = 0, standard deviation = 30) to a colored image.

First: You can add the awgn noise of mean = 0, standard deviation = 30 to each of Red, Green, and Blue channels independently (or any other color model-HSI, YUV, Lab); and then combine the noisy channels to form the colored noisy image.

Second: To use the in-built function to add noise to the colored image directly. eg. imnoise() in Matlab.

I tried with both the methods (imnoise and independently), I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned "I have tried to add the noise only in the color channel.
Convert the Input image into YUV Color space
Add the Noise only in the UV Color Channels & Keep the Y channel unaltered."

If you are using the YUV color model, I would suggest you do the opposite. Keep U, and V channel unaltered and add noise only to the Y channel only.