# Adding gaussian noise to rgb image opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, gaussian

I tried adding gaussian noise to rgn image, m=0 s=3.
Tried this: 
      m=(0,0,0)
      S=(3,3,3)
      cv2.randn(img, m, s)

The result is a black image with white dots...
What may be the problem ?

Comment: show us your full code with some outputs!

Comment: you may find this question relevent!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005094/how-to-add-noise-to-color-image-opencv